# Does the FD Feedburner plugin create feeds for categories

Tags: feed, feedburner

I have setup the [FD Feedburner plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/feedburner-plugin/).  I want to get feeds for each of my categories.  Do I need to manually create feeds for categories in Feedburner? or Does the plugin automatically create feeds for categories.

Here is another older [link](http://flagrantdisregard.com/feedburner/) to the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is how it works:

You need to manually create feeds in Feedburner.com for categories.  You can use a URL like this:
feeds.feedburner.com/Lovefood_burgers

In wordpress you would create the main feed in the FD Feedburner plugin:
feeds.feedburner.com/Lovefood

Choose the option:
Append category/tag to URL for category/tag feeds ...

Now when you select a category feed in Wordpress, it will redirect to the category feed that you setup in Feedburner.com

btw, I am pretty sure this is correct.  However, I figured this out by experimenting, not be looking at source code or by validation from anyone else (i tried) - so there is a chance I could be incorrect.